# How to Group Sub Pages in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I'm wondering if there's a way in Orchard or a plugin/module that anybody knows of that will let you create subpages in Orchard such that when I go to content -> pages I'm not looking at a huge list of pages; I want to see a list of main pages with their sub pages grouped under them?

Is this possible?

On a related note...when you're working with a navigation widget (that uses a menu) I want to highlight the main item as a current nav item when I'm on a "subpage".

For example, my Company page has a separate leadership page that I would want to highlight the company nav bar item (since leadership is a subpage) when you're on it.

Any recommendations would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could achieve this in Orchard:

1. You could use blogs and blog posts:

   - Blogs are parent pages
   - Blog Posts are child pages
   - Blog posts can have URL that consists of blog's URL which you can use to create your menu.
2. You could also use `Orchard.Lists` module which enables you to add `Containable` and `Container` parts to get the functionality similar to blogs, but for other content types. You can check the tutorial on how to do it [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists)
3. You could use `Orchard.Taxonomies` module to create a hierarchy of pages and use taxonomies for your menu
4. Lastly, you can do this manually by using ordinary pages and giving them hierarchically named slugs (for example parent page could have URL `/parent` and child page could have slug `/parent/child`). You could then manually create a menu that is hierarchical and consists of pages you created and use slugs to highlight your parent pages in menus..

Comment: Orchard.Lists is a deprecated feature.

Comment: The Tree allows you to explore your hierarchy of content.